# Cant figure out whats wrong with my SQL code

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting a various type of errors such as:

*Error starting at line : 21 in command - 00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"*

*ALTER TABLE COMPONENTS ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERID_FK FOREIGN KEY(SUPPLIERID) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SUPPLIERID);
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"*

But I cant figure out how come the table doesn't exist or even where is the unmatched parenthesis

```
    CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
 PNAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 PID INT,
 QUANTITY INT,
 CID INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(PID,CID)
);

CREATE TABLE COMPONENTS (
CID INT , 
C_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(20),
S_ID INT,
PID INT,
 CONSTRAINT COMPONENTS_PK PRIMARY KEY(PID,CID,S_ID)
);


ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_FK FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES COMPONENTS(CID);
ALTER TABLE COMPONENTS ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUCTID_FK FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PID);
--ALTER TABLE COMPONENTS ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUCTID_FK FOREIGN KEY(PID,CID) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PID,CID);

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER( --on delete /updatecascade
SUPPLIER_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 S_ID INT ,
 PHONE CHAR(14), CONSTRAINT PHONE_FORMAT CHECK (PHONE LIKE '(___) ___-____') ,
 CONSTRAINT SUPPLIER_PK PRIMARY KEY (S_ID)
 );

ALTER TABLE COMPONENTS ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERID_FK FOREIGN KEY(S_ID) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(S_ID);
```

Comment: Your code works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=50ca06cc66c56fb11bc51284b2c702d1

Comment: You've got no column `SUPPLIERID` in your `SUPPLIER` table. And you have some random code `CONSTRAINT SUPPLIER_PK PRIMARY KEY` with no column referenced for this constraint... and your error is giving you a syntax problem with the SUPPLIERID column (that does not exist) in your SUPPLIER table... these two mistakes are surely related. I'd recommend testing this code a LOT more before copying and pasting anything else.

Comment: Hi @sanjep  you have edited your question in a strange way ? This last edit is strange. A mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a primary key or unique constraint in the table COMPONENTS you are referencing to. So this is wrong:

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_FK 
FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES COMPONENTS(CID);
```

But if you create table COMPONENTS  like this:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPONENTS (
CID INT , 
C_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(20),
SUPPLIERID INT,
PID INT,
CONSTRAINT COMPONENTS_PK PRIMARY KEY(PID, CID, SUPPLIERID),
CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (CID) 
);
```

Then you can run that `ALTER` statement.

---

You can have only one primary key in one table so this is wrong:

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER( 
--on delete /updatecascade
SUPPLIER_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
S_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
PHONE CHAR(14), CONSTRAINT PHONE_FORMAT CHECK (PHONE LIKE '(___) ___-____') ,
CONSTRAINT SUPPLIER_PK PRIMARY KEY);
```

And this is ok:

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER( 
--on delete /updatecascade
SUPPLIER_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
S_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
PHONE CHAR(14), CONSTRAINT PHONE_FORMAT CHECK (PHONE LIKE '(___) ___-____'));
```

---

You do not have SUPPLIERID column in your SUPPLIER table, so this is not ok:

```
ALTER TABLE COMPONENTS ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERID_FK 
FOREIGN KEY(SUPPLIERID) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SUPPLIERID);
```

But this would be ok:

```
ALTER TABLE COMPONENTS ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERID_FK 
FOREIGN KEY(SUPPLIERID) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(S_ID);
```

---

**Please note** this is answer only to the question why. This is not an answer how to do something. You know if you need a unique key and a primary key like this.

For the end [here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=581df0db292860cb8292361357999e3e) with a code that works.

Comment: Done the fixes yet i keep getting errors? eg : Error starting at line : 19 in command -
ALTER TABLE COMPONENTS ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUCTID_FK FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PID)
Error report -
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

Comment: Hi @sanjep , I have updated and finished my answer. Your question is not asked in a good way. You should inform the people what error do you get for which line of code. I hope my answer will direct you in right way. Cheers!